# Connection to MSSQL Server Returns NULL

Tags: android, sql, mobile

I want to connect my android app to sql server, but connection always returns null. I did not find anything that helps the same code is everywhere but the problem is the same. What might be the problem?

```
class DatabaseHandler {

 private static Connection connection;
 private static String db,ip,un,pass,connectionURL,port;
 private static Statement statement;


static Connection getConnection(Context context)
{
    //ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context,new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

    ip = "****"; //database ip
    db = "***"; //database name
    un = "***"; //username to connect to db
    pass = "***"; //password to connect to db
    connectionURL = null;
    port = "1433";


    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    if(connection == null)
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            connectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip + ";databaseName=" + db + ";user=" + un+ ";password=" + pass +";";
            connection =  DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
            statement = connection.createStatement();

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Log.i("ifconnectionsucceeded",""+connection);

    return connection;

}
```

Comment: Can you add `Log.i("In Trying");` right after `try {`? Add `Log.i("statement created");` under `statement = ...();`. Also add `Log.i("Catching");` right under `catch (...) {`. Then, when you run again, what information do you see in the log and is there a printed stacktrace?

Comment: Unknown server host name 'Host is unresolved:  my ip contains backslash  i tried using connection string like this: "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://"+ip+"/"+db+";instance=SQL2014;user="+un+";"+"password="+pass+";";  but it also gives me the same error

Answer (score 0):

I Figured it out.. the problem is that i was using jtds jar 1.3.1 i downgraded to 1.2.7 and it worked just fine